# Creating exceptions / rules for online backup programme

Tags: antivirus

The desktop client for a backup provider i use called Backblaze is with very high CPU usage; around 60% of a 2.7ghz i7.

I contacted Backblaze's support and they informed me that Avast anti virus and OSX's built in firewall (which i have enabled) are making the backup very CPU intensive.

They said i should set exceptions for their processes in Avast anti virus and OSX's built in firewall

- a) dose this sound correct ?
- b) Am i weakening my security by doing this ?

Im running OSX 10.10.5

Comment: I can't answer without understanding, why the firewall/avast make the backup CPU intensive. I can't honestly think of any reason, why it should be so. It should either work or not work, using additional CPU sounds weird to me.

Comment: @PeterHarmann thats what i thought too, surely if the process was being blocked it just wouldnt work full stop. Also whats odd is that the process using the CPU is related to the backup client, not Avast or a OSX firewall process.

Comment: @PeterHarmann: it is hard to tell how the backup solution really works but if it creates lots of (temporary) files in the process of backup for example to save some backup state then this might cause the AV to scan lots of new data, thus increasing the load on the CPU.

Comment: @sam Well yes, but I can't confidently say it is impossible. They may be using some sort of encryption or splitting the data into multiple TCP/TLS connections or something similar, that is indeed CPU intensive to bypass the firewall/avast. You may have to ask them, what it is exactly that they do.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich This would show as load in Avast, not in the app itself unless I am misunderstanding how this works.

Comment: @PeterHarmann: AV might inject itself into the file or network handling of processes and activity will probably show up as part of the process then.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It sounds unlikely it would inject into the process, as that would allow the process to modify the avast code, but you might be right that if they hooked system calls, these may show up as load of the calling process.